# Running Oozie to control multiple clusters

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am trying to install a Oozie server which can submit jobs to multiple Hadoop clusters. I did not come across any such deployment, but I see no reason why it cannot be done. But I have not succeeded in doing this so far.

This is what I am doing:
I installed Oozie on a machine (OZ-1) with other Hadoop components. I have a Oozie client on my laptop (OZ-Client-1). Now I want to submit a Pig job to a Hadoop Cluster (HD-1).

1. I created a workflow.xml file and placed it in the HDFS of OZ-1
2. I created the job.properties on the OZ-Client-1 which defines the following properties:

   `nameNode=hdfs:HD-1:PORT`

   `jobTracker=HD-1:PORT`

   `queueName=default`

   `examplesRoot=examples`

   `oozie.use.system.libpath=true`

   `oozie.wf.application.path=OZ-1/path/to/workflow.xml`
3. I copy the Pig script I want to run, to the HDFS of OZ-1.
4. Now, I submit the Oozie job from the client, OZ-Client-1
5. The input data is already present in the Hadoop Cluster: HD-1

Is there anything wrong in the steps I am following? This just does not work and I get the following logs on the Oozie client:

```
Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000001-131020152954824-oozie-shar-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000001-131020152954824-oozie-shar-W@pig-node                                 START_RETRY-                      -          JA009     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what's in logs in Job History? it's at HD-1:50030/jobhistory.jsp

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?